# make command does not recognize .o File format

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, g++

I'm trying to install a software using make on Ubuntu. The software is called Kakadu. I'm following the installing instructor in [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/JP2KAK). On command make -f Makefile-Linux-x86-64-gcc , I get this error:

```
ar -rv ../../lib/Linux-x86-64-gcc/libkdu.a *.o
r - analysis.o
r - avx2_colour_local.o
r - avx2_dwt_local.o
r - avx_coder_local.o
r - avx_colour_local.o
r - block_coding_common.o
r - block_decoder.o
r - block_encoder.o
r - blocks.o
r - codestream.o
r - colour.o
r - compressed.o
r - decoder.o
r - encoder.o
r - kdu_arch.o
r - kdu_threads.o
r - kernels.o
r - messaging.o
r - mq_decoder.o
r - mq_encoder.o
r - multi_transform.o
r - params.o
r - roi.o
r - ssse3_coder_local.o
r - ssse3_colour_local.o
r - ssse3_dwt_local.o
r - synthesis.o
ranlib ../../lib/Linux-x86-64-gcc/libkdu.a
g++ -I../common -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wno-unused-function   -fPIC -m64 -msse2 -DKDU_X86_INTRINSICS  -shared -o ../../lib/Linux-x86-64-gcc/libkdu_v77R.so *.o
params.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libkdu_v77R.so] Error 1
```

Since I do have g++ installed, why is params.o not recognized but other .o files were ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
make -f Makefile-Linux-x86-64-gcc clean
```